# firebase cloud function call from client redirect me to accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

When I am calling a firebase cloud function https request it is redirected to
accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue={my-cloud-function-http-url}

Here my firebase.json (hosting config)

```
...
"hosting": {
  "public": "client/dist",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/v1/**",
      "function": "midleman"
    },
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "trailingSlash": false
},
...
```

Is it a bug from google firebase or I've missed a configuration ?

Comment: Since you're showing a Firebase Hosting configuration, are you saying that you're accessing a URL that should be serviced by Cloud Functions?  Could you edit the question to be more specific about what you're doing, and what you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @DougStevenson  The thing is that I want to rewrite/redirect all call to my-app-url.web.app/api/v1/* to the cloud function midleman. But firebase redirect it to account.google.com/ServiceLogin

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the URL you are trying to access is unreachable (`404 Not Found`). Make sure you have entered the right URL in your HTTP client and try again.

For example, you are trying to access `https://us-central1-[project_id].cloudfunctions.net/london`
but you have entered `https://us-central1-[project_id].cloudfunctions.net/new-york`. If the latest is not a valid function name, you will be redirected to the Google sign-in page.